# Pasar 2 ID mediante AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy realizando el siguiente ejercicio, donde al agregar a un estudiante a una materia con requisitos establecidos anteriormente, debo de cargar los documentos faltantes si así fuera el caso.

El escenario es el siguiente.

1.- Al crear al estudiante a una materia me redirecciona al listado de requisitos de dicha materia para cargar la documentación faltante [image: anexo imagen]

2.- El botón azul me sirve para mostrar un modal y cargar el documento.

El problema que tengo es que quisiera pasar dos ID (El ID de la materia y el ID del estudiante).

Anexo el código de mi tabla donde muestro los requisitos y donde solamente paso el ID del requisito de materia.

[image: Anexo Imagen]

y este es mi código AJAX donde recibo el ID.

[image: Espero y logre poder explicarme bien y espero y puedan ayudarme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede poner otra variable en el td usando data:

```
<td class="" id="$id" data-materia="$idMateria"></td>
```

luego en Js recuperas ese valor:

```
var personal_id = $(this).attr("id");
var materia_id = $(this).data("materia");
```

y ya teniendo el materia_id en js lo puedes enviar en el data:

```
data:{
 personal_id,
 materia_id,
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @JuanPerez, me ha servido tu ayuda.